# Is it possible to have multiple hive tables represented within the same HDFS directory structure?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Is it possible to have multiple hive tables represented within the same HDFS directory structure? In other words, is there a way to have multiple hive tables pointing to same/overlapping HDFS paths?

Here is my situation:

I have a table named "mytable", located in hdfs:/tables/mytable

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable
(
id int,
...
[a whole bunch of columns]
...
PARTITIONED BY (logname STRING)
STORED AS [I-do-not-know-what-just-yet]
LOCATION 'hdfs:/tables/mytable';
```

So, HDFS will look like:

```
hdfs:/tables/mytable/logname=tarzan/....
hdfs:/tables/mytable/logname=jane/....
hdfs:/tables/mytable/logname=whoa/....
```

Is it possible to have a hive table, named "tarzan", located in hdfs:/tables/mytable/logname=tarzan ?  Same with hive table "jane", located in hdfs:/tables/mytable/logname=jane, etc.

The tarzan, jane, whoa, etc sub-tables share some columns (timestamp, ip_address, country, user_id, and some others), but there will also be a lot of columns that they do not have in common.

Is there a way to store this data once in HDFS, and use it for multiple tables as I described above?  Furthermore, is there a way to store the data in an efficient way, since many of the tables will have columns that are not in common?  Would a file format like RCFILE or PARQUET work in this case?

Thanks so much for any hints or help anyone can provide,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can have multiple hive tables with the same underlying HDFS directory.

Example:

1. Create table `emp` and load data file `file3` into it.

   ```
   create table emp (id int, name string, salary int) 
   row format delimited 
   fields terminated by ','  
   -- default location would be used

   load data 
   local inpath '/home/parv/testfiles/file3' 
   into table emp;
   ```
2. Create another table `mirror`.  When you will select data from `mirror` table, it would be as same as of `emp` table (contents of file3).

   ```
   create table mirror (id int, name string, salary int) 
   row format delimited 
   fields terminated by ',' 
   location 'hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/parv.db/base';
   ```
3. Load data into `mirror` table.  When you will select data either from `mirror` table or `emp` table, it would return same results (contents of file3 and file4).

   ```
   load data 
   local inpath '/home/parv/testfiles/file4' 
   into table mirror;
   ```

Conclusion:

1. Same data files are shared among both tables `emp` and `mirror`.
2. But, strange, the HDFS filesystem only shows data directory for `emp` table and not for `mirror` table.  However, both the tables are present in hive and so can be queried.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

It IS possible to have multiple hive tables represented by the same HDFS directory structure, but for what I am looking to do:

1. A mytable table partitioned by logname (logname=tarzan, logname=jane, etc...)
2. A separate table for each logname: A "tarzan" table with only columns used by the tarzan table, and not any other logname, same for the "jane" table, etc
3. Only represent the data one time in HDFS

A better solution is to have the 1 mytable table, partitioned by logname, AND create views for each logname table, with only the subset of columns needed in each.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could point multiple tables to the same location on HDFS.  However, Hive doesn't support dynamic columns.

Is there a reason you can't just have 3 different tables?  This would allow you do have different schemas (columns) for each.

--Brandon